# Double exterior derivative

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-algebra

In the proof of $d(d\omega)=0$ for all k-form $\omega=f_Idx^I=f_I \wedge dx^I$. We compute
$$
d(d\omega)=d(d(f_I \wedge dx^I))=df_I\wedge d(dx^I) + d(df_I)\wedge dx^I=df_I\wedge d(dx^I)=0
$$

Where the third equality is because the double exterior derivative of any 0-form is zero since mixed partial commutes. Now in the last equality, the proof goes:

$$
d(dx^I)=d(1)\wedge dx^I=0
$$

But I don't understand why $d(dx^I)=d(1)\wedge dx^I$. I know that $dx^I$ will be the sum of the wedge of k number of 1-forms but I don't think that is relevant here.

Comment: what definition of exterior derivative are you using?

Comment: It is defined by basis, and I'm trying to prove a fact from the "definition of exterior derivative" that is basis independent.

Comment: Im not sure i understand your problem then. Given the definition of exterior differentiation you know how to prove $ddx^I=0$ directly from the definition, but you ask why is it independent of the choice of basis?

Comment: I was saying that my definition of exterior derivative I'm using is basis dependent. And the fact I'm trying to prove is usually said to be the basis independent definition of exterior derivative. But my question is why $d(dx^I)=d(1)\wedge dx^I$. Sorry if it was confusing.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly you are using the following definition of exterior differentiation. The differential  operator
$$
d: \Omega^{q}\left(\mathbb{R}^{m}\right) \rightarrow \Omega^{q+1}\left(\mathbb{R}^{m}\right)
$$
defined as follows:

1. if $f \in \Omega^{0}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$, then $d f=\sum \partial f / \partial x_{i} d x_{i}$
2. if $\omega=\sum f_{I} d x^{I}$, then $d \omega=\sum d f_{I} d x^{I}$.

If this is the case then we just note that $dx^I=1\cdot dx^I$, where $1\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^m)$ is just the constant function. It follws from the definition of the directional derivative that $\frac{\partial 1 }{\partial x_i}=0$ for all $1\le i \le m$. Thus when computing $d(dx^I)$ we get $$\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{\partial 1 }{\partial x_i}dx_i \wedge dx^I=0.$$
This is what we wanted to prove.